# Resource/Asset Manager

Tags: c++, architecture, loading, assets, resource-management

I'm creating a `ResourceManager`.
At the beginning i'm creating a groups of resources which contain a map of resources. The role of groups is to quick load/unload resources, to find some constant, never unloading resources which placing to group, for example named `Static` and newer trying to unload, or find resources common for 2 scenes, or batches etc, this is work of pipeline. Also resource names are hashes of string, they are all unique and its checked off-line.

After i'm adding archives, where assets is stored and load table of contents and put it into group. After i'm calling `InitializeGroup` where i'm creating a raw resources with out creating or loading some data, only passing to them the `Location`, where their data is stored.

```
struct Location
{   
    Archive* pArchive;

    size_t m_Offset;
    size_t m_Size;
};

class ResourceManager 
{
public:     
    struct RacingEngineExport ResourceGroup
    {           
        LocationMap m_Locations;
        ResorceMap m_ResorceMap;
        String m_Name;
    };

    void CreateGroup(const String& name);
    void AddLocation(const String& path, const Archive::Type lType, const ResourceGroupName& group, bool recursive = true);

    void InitialiseGroup(const String& name);

    void RegisterResourceHandler(ResourceHandler* pResourceHandler);;

protected:

    ResourceGroupMap            m_ResourceGroups;
};
```

For each Resource type like `Mesh`, `Texture` etc. i'm creating specific `ResourceHandler`. `ResourceHandler` responsible to retrieve data from archive(not load, just ask some background queue to load it) and prepare resource for future using, also it's creating and unloading them.

```
class ResourceHandler
{
public:
    inline ResourcePtr Get(const ResourceID& id);
    ResourcePtr Create(const ResourceName& name, const PropertyMap& properties = PropertyMap(), const bool isManual = false);
    inline void Load(ResourcePtr pResource);
    inline void Unload(ResourcePtr pResource);
    inline void Destroy(ResourcePtr pResource);
}
```

In `Load` it's retrieving `Archive` from `Resource::Location::pArchive`, loading data from disk and creating some other stuff specific for `Resource` type.

So when the resource needed by some one, it's calling `ResourceManager`, retrieving `ResourcePtr` and asking `ResourceHandler` to load it if it's not loaded, `ResourceHandler` somehow (async or sync) loading it and returning ready to use resource.
So now the resources ready to load.

This model not friendly to real-time adding new resources, but it's possible, but i don't need it, just it's can't be loaded again after unload automatically.

So, the question is where i have to store resources, in the main `ResourceManager`, in all `ResourceHandler`, in Groups or everywhere? Also i want to hear some recommendations how to improve my impl. or defects in it, or some better way to manage resources. May be my question is stupid but i can't get rid of thoughts that that it's not OK at all.

Comment: Resource managers are a well discussed topic, whats more interesting is how you request and return resources. Using an Async messaging paradigm is usually preferred. Also, don't bother hashing string names, just do the compares. Its unlikely to be your bottleneck, and its far easier to debug.

Comment: as a simplification, i would hold all of my resources in my manager and simply have pointers to them wherever you need. the manager will manage them and the handler decides how it is to be used/managed/whatever

Comment: Whatever you do. *dont* have pointer to them wherever you need. As this complicates situations where the Resource Manager needs to delete, or move resources that are in-memory. It will also complicate the situation where you request a resource but it hasnt finished loading yet (ghost resources). At worst, use a smart pointer. At best, dont hand out the actual resource, but give out an object which lets other subsystems know which resource to interrogate the resource system about when they need to.

Comment: @MattD , Yes, I've wanted to use it, the some loader loading the resource from disk to memory mapped file and giving the access to it via interface to `ResourceHandler`. But I don't know, i am also using Entity/Component models where the entity is just ID and `Component` is a data and all processing is going in `System` a lot of groups of `Systems` which can run simultaneously and I've wanted to create some `ThreadPool` which have `n` `Threads` and can receive some requests and put some `RequestHandlers` to threads to process 'em. But i have some doubts about that.

Comment: @MattD, I also think about that. I've want to create something like
    `struct ObjPtr<T> 

    { T* pObj; 
    protected: 

        friend class MemoryManager; 

        void ObjectMoved(T* newLocation);

    }`